# What is geth doing?

Tags: go-ethereum

I installed **go-ethereum** via `brew` today (osx) and I created a new account. When I run `$ geth` I see an endless list of

```
INFO [06-26|17:56:59] Imported new block receipts            count=47   elapsed=25.671ms  number=3810452 hash=5ec9c0…8f07fb ignored=0 
INFO [06-26|17:57:01] Imported new block receipts            count=55   elapsed=163.820ms number=3810507 hash=5319b1…947eb1 ignored=0 
INFO [06-26|17:57:02] Imported new block receipts            count=26   elapsed=64.938ms  number=3810533 hash=fc5aa7…d7a33f ignored=0 
INFO [06-26|17:57:04] Imported new block receipts            count=142  elapsed=341.847ms number=3810675 hash=b8b3af…594219 ignored=0 
INFO [06-26|17:57:05] Imported new block receipts            count=39   elapsed=85.936ms  number=3810714 hash=8f7b44…008241 ignored=0 
INFO [06-26|17:57:06] Imported new block receipts            count=48   elapsed=214.607ms number=3810762 hash=f270db…b82dbc ignored=0 
INFO [06-26|17:57:07] Imported new block receipts            count=99   elapsed=148.928ms number=3810861 hash=dea7b3…e914b9 ignored=0
```

From the [go-ethereum github page](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) I understand`$ geth` as

> Our main Ethereum CLI client. It is the entry point into the Ethereum
>   network (main-, test- or private net), capable of running as a full
>   node (default) archive node (retaining all historical state) or a
>   light node (retrieving data live). It can be used by other processes
>   as a gateway into the Ethereum network via JSON RPC endpoints exposed
>   on top of HTTP, WebSocket and/or IPC transports. geth --help and the
>   CLI Wiki page for command line options

I still have no idea what this means. Can someone explain in newbie terms what is going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my limited knowledge geth is synchronizing with the mainnet. This usually takes time to sync and once done you are connected to the mainnet.

Try `geth --help` on the command line to see all options you could use to start geth.

Comment: Makes sense. I'm thinking `geth --mine` is what I was looking for.